# pg_cron install: No cron tables created

Tags: postgresql, cron, pg

I am running ThingsBoard (Internet-of-Things) on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VPS, using a PostgreSQL DB. Since the IoT devices send a lot of data to the DB, I need to clean regularly the DB.

For this, I would like to use pg_cron.

I followed the steps described at https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron:

1. I installed postgresql-10-cron
2. I modified postgresql.conf:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'postgres'
```

3. I restarted the DB by

```
service postgresql restart
```

4. I logged into my postgres DB with Adminer and executed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

=> Success

However, I cannot see any tables in postgres that I could configure...

I tried step 4 again, with the result 
ERROR: extension "pg_cron" already exists

Is there anything I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

The metadata tables are created in the `cron` schema:

```
\dt cron.*
```

To find all objects that belong to the extension, run

```
\dx+ pg_cron
```

Comment: does installing pg_cron always happen at `postgres` schema? if I want to run pg_cron for `database_X`, what should I do ? In many articles, I always find `cron.database_name = 'postgres'`

Comment: @padjee You mean the `postgres` *database*, not the `postgres` schema (there is a difference; this is not MySQL). It does not matter in which database you install it.

Comment: yes @LaurenzAlbe. I meant `postgres` database. Sorry. So if I want to have `pg_cron` on all databases, then I need to add a few of lines, such as: `cron.database_name = 'DB1 cron.database_name = 'DB2 cron.database_name = 'DB3'` on my `postgresql.conf` and create on each one of them using `CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;`

Comment: I don't think that is related to the question above.